# Where are my Golden Keys?

Tags: achievements, borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I'm on my first playthrough and just got to Concordia.  I was surprised to find that when I approached the golden chest, I had no keys to open it!  I was expecting to have the three keys which were given by Gearbox for having the previous games installed.

What happened to my golden keys?